# Custom Properties - Change subtype default value (Python API)

Tags: python, properties, custom-properties

Using the Blender Python API, I am creating a float array custom property for the selected object using the following code:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

float_array = "Paint - Custom Color"
obj[float_array] = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
obj.id_properties_ensure()
property_manager = obj.id_properties_ui(float_array)
property_manager.update(
    default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), min=0.0, max=1.0, soft_min=0.0, soft_max=1.0
)
```

Is there a way to change the default subtype value from 'Plain Data' to 'Linear Color'[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subtype` argument in the `update` method.

```
property_manager.update(
    default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
    min=0.0, 
    max=1.0, 
    soft_min=0.0, 
    soft_max=1.0, 
    subtype="COLOR"
)
```

Other possible values are defined in [the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/property_subtype_number_array_items.html#property-subtype-number-array-items).

```
COLOR
TRANSLATION
DIRECTION
VELOCITY
ACCELERATION
MATRIX
EULER
QUATERNION
AXISANGLE
XYZ
XYZ_LENGTH
COLOR_GAMMA
COORDINATES
LAYER
LAYER_MEMBER
NONE
```

You can find all the available arguments in [the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty).

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks